# Gradle project sync failed, connection timed out:connect

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I started studying with a android example project named "HelloWorld2", i started emulator, next i gradle the project, but it occurs with following errors:

> Gradle project sync failed. Error:Connection timed out: connect

[image: Messages Gradle Sync]

[image: logs are as follows:]

Answer (score 4):

Go to gradle settings and make sure you have checked the offline work checkbox.

`Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build tools -> Gradle`

and trying resyncing the project